# How should I format a logit regression to test company motivations? (R)

Tags: regression, logistic-regression, logits

I'm writing a paper on investment firms and their relationship with a sustainable finance initiative. I'm using a panel dataset with 307 investors, 125 of them signed this sustainable initiative.

I would like to add in a section in which I test which variables might be driving them to sign this initiative.

I believe I should use logit regression for this, but having not used these extensively, I'm looking for some guidance.

Currently the data looks like this:

| investor | year | activity | country | region | strategy | signatory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 IM | 2002 | 4.45 | France | europe | VC | 1 |
| 123 IM | 2003 | 3.2 | France | europe | VC | 1 |
| 123 IM | 2004 | 7.8 | France | europe | VC | 1 |
| Aegon | 2005 | 5.4 | Netherlands | europe | BY | 0 |
| Aegon | 2006 | 4.2 | Netherlands | europe | BY | 0 |
| Aegon | 2007 | 1.3 | Netherlands | europe | BY | 0 |

As you can see the signatory variable is a binary, and I would be looking to test variables such as country or region against it.

Any tips would be appreciated!

Rory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the glm function in R. Following is an example with country and activity variables as independent variables:

```
# Assuming that your dataframe name is df
my_logit <- glm(signatory ~ activity + country, family = 'binomial', data=df)
# Check the output summary
summary(my_logit)
```